# How do I get through 80,000 downloads in Java, concurrently?

Tags: java, multithreading, git, github, server

I'm cloning a large sample of GitHub projects for an empirical study. I'm assuming it will be faster to download the 80,000 projects with some concurrency, but that's a lot to download.

How can I start ~1,000 processes and then start another after each one finishes? Or, is there some other way I should go about this? Will downloading this much at a faster-than-sequential rate be bad for GitHub's servers?

Here's the relevant code so far:

```
// Create a CountDownLatch that will only reach 0 when all repositories
// have been downloaded
CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(numberOfRepositories);

// Start the download for each git repository
for (String URL : gitURLs)
{
    new Thread(new Worker(doneSignal, URL)).start();
}

doneSignal.await();
```

Worker:

```
public class Worker implements Runnable
{
    private final CountDownLatch doneSignal;
    private final String URL;

    Worker (CountDownLatch doneSignal, String URL)
    {
        this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
        this.URL = URL;
    }

    @Override
    public void run ()
    {
        try
        {
            // Run the command line process to download
            ProcessBuilder pb =
                new ProcessBuilder("git", "clone", "--depth=1", URL, "projects/" + getProjectName(URL));
            Process p = pb.start();
            p.waitFor();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        doneSignal.countDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyway, I guess Github's servers wouldn't let you start so many DL at the same time from the same IP.

Comment: Yeah I would hope not.

Answer (score 3):

It's bad for github's servers but it's even worse for your performance. Try maybe 5 or so instead of 1000. To limit the code to X parallel threads, you could use a pool:

```
CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(numberOfRepositories);
// Start the download for each git repository
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
for (String URL : gitURLs) {
    pool.execute(new Worker(doneSignal, URL));
}
pool.shutdown();
doneSignal.await();
```

Also works without the latch because you can wait for the pool to become idle via e.g.

```
pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Java 8 and parallelStream for multithreading your downloads

```
    List<String> gitURLs = new ArrayList<>();

    gitURLs.parallelStream().forEach(
        URL ->
        {
            try
            {
                // Run the command line process to download
                ProcessBuilder pb =
                        new ProcessBuilder("git", "clone", "--depth=1", URL, "projects/" + getProjectName(URL));
                Process p = pb.start();
                p.waitFor();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use multi-threading and custom Java code for a simple task like this. Especially since each thread just spawns an external process using the CLI. It's over-engineering, and you could get the job done more quickly by using something simpler.

It looks like you probably already have a file with the URLs of all the projects you want to clone. I would use a few commands in my text editor (Sublime Text) to add `git clone --depth=1` to the beginning of each line and `&` to the end (this runs a command asynchronously). If your text editor can't do that easily, a little bash/awk/Perl/Ruby/Python/etc script could do it in no more than a few lines.

Then your list of URLs becomes... a valid shell script, which will clone all the repos in parallel! And you can run it as such.

Note, though, that while running parallel downloads *will* help you, 1000 is way too many. You can experiment with the number, but you will probably find that running more than 20 at the same time will not help.